# Extract string from column with grep

Tags: shell, grep, awk

I have a column based .txt file and I want to grep output the Common Name, having a little trouble.

```
V   300223164711Z       01  unknown /C=UK/O=LMG/OU=server/CN=server/name=server/emailAddress=support@kam.org
V   300223170002Z       02  unknown /C=UK/O=LMF/OU=server/CN=test/name=server/emailAddress=support@kam.org
V   300223170935Z       03  unknown /C=UK/O=risk/OU=server/CN=risk/name=server/emailAddress=support@kam.org
```

My current grep output does the following:

```
tail -n +2 index.txt | grep "^V" | cut -d '/' -f 5 | nl -s ') '
```

```
     1) CN=test
     2) CN=risk
```

I only want the name to be the output,  'test' or 'risk'.
What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `awk` you can do it on this way (assuming the place of CN is always the same:

```
awk -F\/ '$5~"test"|| $5~"risk" {gsub("CN=","",$5);print $5}'
```

To add the number of the line where you find a CN records you can use code like this:

```
awk -F\/ '$5~"test"|| $5~"risk" {gsub("CN=","",$5);print NR") "$5 }'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With the awk code you supplied it still produces "CN=test" & "CN=risk".

Comment: @Kam-ALIEN, aaa, you want to get only the name of CN. Check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just what I needed.

Comment: @Kam-ALIEN, if you are happy with my answer feel free to upvote and/or accept it :)

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, not very familiar with awk lastly what would I need to include to the end of the command to maintain the numbering 1)test  2)risk ?

Comment: @Kam-ALIEN, i update the answer. And you will get the line (in source file) where particular CN was found. In your case the output will be 2) test 3) risk. Is this what you want?

Comment: You're a legend! Wish I had enough rep to up-vote. Most definitely given me a better understanding of the structure. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kam-ALIEN, there is one tick you can click on (for accepting answer). You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

**sed** should be one of your friends

```
echo CN=test | sed -e 's/CN=//'
test
```